# Generating reset_password_token in non-Devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am processing a form a new controller and using the email, I want to automatically send the user a reset password email. Is there some kind of Devise short-code I have to call in order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `Recoverable` set up, your `User` model should have a `send_reset_password_instructions` method available. To use it, do something like this in your controller:

```
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
 user.send_reset_password_instructions
 flash[:notice] = "Reset password instructions have been sent to #{user.email}."
 redirect_to whatever_path
```

For more on this method, see the documentation: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable#send_reset_password_instructions-instance_method.